# Jquery not removing class on keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to hide a div and show another on a keyup event. It doesn't work I don't know why:

```
<div class = "beta_form">
<form id = "beta_form" class = "form-horizontal">
    <label for="beta_password" class = "control-label">
    </label>
    <input id = "beta_password" name = "beta_password" type = "text" class = "form-control">
</form>
</div>

<div class = "facebook_twitter hidden">
  <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Inicia sesión con Facebook
  </a>
</div>


$("#beta_password").keyup(function(){
    if ($(this).val() === '1789'){
        $("#facebook_twitter").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#beta_form").addClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#facebook_twitter")
```

is supposed to be

```
$(".facebook_twitter")
```

- class selector

Comment: Thanks. Sry for the dumb question.

Comment: @alejoss . No worries :) .